# hyperrefs/hypertargets and counters in \newcommand

Tags: macros, pandoc

I'm trying to create a custom "theorem" environment so pandoc will generate a `<div>` with an id corresponding to the theorem name in the html. Hypertarget/hyperref work well for this, but I can't get this to work as a command (I am not worried at the moment if pandoc doesnt render the counter, but I want it in the tex -> pdf version). It should also work as a "passable" replacement for amsthm.

The issue I am having is with the `thm` and `refthm` commands, pdflatex complains about missing numbers and too many arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{parskip}
\newcounter{theorem}[section]
\newcommand{thm}[2]{\refstepcounter{theorem}\hypertarget{#1}{{\bfseries{Theorem~\thetheorem}}(\#1).\emph{\#2}}}
\newcommand{refthm}[1]{\hyperlink{\#1}{(\#1)}} 

\begin{document}
  \section{Introduction}
  \thm{Euc1}{There is no largest prime.}

  By there \refthm{Euc1} are infinitely many primes.     
\end{document}
```

I would expect the output in the tex->pdf to produce something like

**Theorem 1** (Euc1). *There is no largest prime*

while in html

**Theorem** (Euc1). *There is no largest prime*

Comment: Welcome! What's the purpose of the backslashes in front of the `#1`? Did you mean to write `\newcommand{\thm}[2]{\refstepcounter{theorem}\hypertarget{#1}{{\bfseries{Theorem~\thetheorem}}(#1).\emph{#2}}}
\newcommand{\refthm}[1]{\hyperlink{#1}{(#1)}} `?

Comment: ```You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.``` It needs the \# in the second part of the hyperref.

Comment: BTW, you probably should include the section number in \thetheorem, as it is reset to 0 every section (duplicates).

Answer (score 1):

Missing a `\` in the newcommand.

```
\newcommand{\thm}[2]{\refstepcounter{theorem}\hypertarget{#1}{{\bfseries{Theorem~\thetheorem}}(#1).\emph{#2}}} 
\newcommand{\refthm}[1]{\hyperlink{#1}{(#1)}}
```